# Python accessing AWS SQS message created by S3

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

Whenever a file is uploaded to S3, I appreciate that S3 can write a message to SQS. However, accessing the file name ("key":"filename.txt") in the SQS message body from Python is a bit problematic since it's a dictionary that contains a list with multiple dictionaries.

Has anyone accessed the filename in the SQS message body when *that message was created by an S3 event*?

The full message is:

```
{
    "Records": [{
        "eventVersion": "2.0",
        "eventSource": "aws:s3",
        "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
        "eventTime": "2016-12-04T22:14:52.325Z",
        "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
        "userIdentity": {
            "principalId": "ABC123"
        },
        "requestParameters": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "12.345.687.899"
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "x-amz-request-id": "ABC123",
            "x-amz-id-2": "ABCDEF"
        },
        "s3": {
            "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "configurationId": "MyQueueName",
            "bucket": {
                "name": "mybucket",
                "ownerIdentity": {
                    "principalId": "ABC123"
                },
                "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "filename.txt",
                "size": 2310,
                "eTag": "defg123",
                "sequencer": "00345"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that isnt a standard JSON response message that you have to parse?

Comment: Also,  `"object":"key":"filename.txt"` isnt valid JSON or Python dictionary syntax, so iI think you are missing some escape characters

Comment: @cricket_007 I think that's a typo -- this message has been sanitized.  It's actually `"object":{"key":"filename.txt","size": ...`... yes, standard JSON.  OP needs to extract (pseudocode) from_json(this)->Records[0]->object->key.  Perhaps you can assist with that? I'm very familiar with this JSON data structure but I'm not a python person.  The Records array always only has 1 member (this data structure is a common one used by multple AWS services, which is why this is an array at all).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Should take a about 10-15 minutes to go over the builtin `json` library of the Python documentation if you wanted to try

Comment: I completely agree, @cricket_007 ... but I'm not the OP. I just threw that comment in to help try to clarify the apparent nature of the question, and to point out that your observation about the data structure was spot-on accurate, but that this isn't precisely what the original JSON string looks like -- many of the string values have been replaced with dummy values and the missing `{` is almost certainly an accidental artifact of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your question to be proper [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
import json
# message = get_sqs_message()
message = json.loads(message)
print(message["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"])
```

Should output `filename.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was receiving an error --> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'list'. The following 3 commands work and return the file name: message = queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=1)

jsonmsg = json.loads(message[0].body)

jsonmsg["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]

Comment: Yes, I didn't know the format of the message you were receiving. But, you figured it out ..`message[0].body`